# How to specify a multiple column index correctly in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing

As shown in this question: 
[How do I make a column unique and index it in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449459/how-to-make-column-unique-and-index-it-in-rails-migration)
You can write:

```
add_index :the_table, [:foo_column, :bar_column], unique: true
```

to add an multiple column index.
But is it still required to add an single indexes for each of those columns that you already have specified a multi-column index?

I mean something like writing below code **in additional to** the code shown above.

```
add_index :the_table, :foo_column  
add_index :the_table, :bar_column
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For MySQL :

MySQL will be able to use the index [:foo_column, :bar_column] to query for conditions on both columns, and also for conditions on the left column only, but NOT the right column.

More info here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

So you should do

```
add_index :the_table, [:foo_column, :bar_column], :unique => true
add_index :the_table, :bar_column
```

To make sure you index everything properly

MySQL indexes columns left-to-right so if you have a multi-column index like this : `[:col1, :col2, :col3, :col4]`, you can query this index on :

- col1
- col1 + col2
- col1 + col2 + col3
- col1 + col2 + col3 + col4

So you can query the **left-most columns**

If you need anything else, you'll have to create more indexes

Again, that's only for MySQL, postgres may work differently

Comment: Wow, I really didn't imagine this answer. It seems like a quite odd behavior for me. Since the documentation says that MySQL checks columns from left-to-right order, is that mean you need to add indexes for every column except for the first one (when specifying more than 2 columns in multi-column index)?

Comment: Ah... never mind. It looks like it behaves like I just commented. The doc says "it also acts like an index for the **left-most** column".

Comment: Edited my answer with more info, it's the left-most columns <= plural!

Comment: I see! Now I understand what 'left-most columns' mean. English is difficult.

Comment: wish I have 8 hands, so I could give this answer 8 thumbs up ..thx

Comment: What about NULL columns?

Comment: Nothing special regarding NULL columns ... you can specify IS NULL or IS NOT NULL instead of a value for each column

Answer (score 7):

For PostgreSQL:

[PostgreSQL: Documentation: Multicolumn Indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) says:

> A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with **query conditions that
>   involve any subset** of the index's columns, but the index is most
>   efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost)
>   columns. **The exact rule is that equality constraints on leading
>   columns, plus any inequality constraints on the first column that does
>   not have an equality constraint**, will be used to limit the portion of
>   the index that is scanned. Constraints on columns to the right of
>   these columns are checked in the index, so they save visits to the
>   table proper, but they do not reduce the portion of the index that has
>   to be scanned.

It seems like PostgreSQL behaves the same as MySQL in this area.