# Ruby on Rails - Migrations, unique columns and indexing (using arrays)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

This question has been asked here, but an answer gave me a follow-up question.

[How do I make a column unique and index it in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449459/how-to-make-column-unique-and-index-it-in-rails-migration)

```
add_index :table_name, :column_name, :unique => true
```

To index multiple columns together, you pass an array of column names instead of a single column nam

```
add_index :table_name, [:column_name_a, :column_name_b]
```

I was browsing some code on the web and came across this snippet.

```
class AddIndexesToSyllabus < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :syllabuses, :template_id, unique: true
    add_index :syllabuses, :edit_id, unique: true
    add_index :syllabuses, :view_id, unique: true
  end
end
```

I had no idea what unique: true did so I searched and came across the aforementioned link. However, I must ask this question. Is it possible to re-arrange that code like this.

```
class AddIndexesToSyllabus < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :syllabuses, [:template_id, edit_id, view_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

In the above example, we have the table name, syllabuses along with three column-names(template_id, edit_id and view_id). The previous question led me to believe that the above is possible, but there was no confirmation. I'm trying to learn how to write efficient code and my suggestion is a lot more efficient. Would this work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create unique indexes either way, but the two methods are not equivalent.

Defining the multi-column index will ensure uniqueness of the combination of columns, so these combinations would all be valid:

```
+-------------+---------+---------+
| template_id | edit_id | view_id |
+-------------+---------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |       1 |
+-------------+---------+---------+
|           1 |       2 |       1 |
+-------------+---------+---------+
|           2 |       1 |       1 |
+-------------+---------+---------+
```

Whereas with the individual indexes, all but the first combination would fail.