# Ensure Rails database record uniqueness when updating without aborting the update process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rake-task

Ruby 2.3.0, Rails 4.2.4, and actually using postgreSQL rather than SQLite

**Updated for clarity**

I have a large csv file (externally updated & downloaded daily) and wrote a method to update a Rails database table. **I do not want the method to append all rows to the database without validating uniqueness**, so I use this great solution ([How do I make a column unique and index it in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449459/how-to-make-column-unique-and-index-it-in-rails-migration)) with `add_index`.

I'm using a rake file to store the executable update code and I enter `$ rake update_task` in my terminal (which works IF the table has no duplicates with the imported csv rows). The problem with this is that the database ABORTS (`rake aborted!`) the rake when it encounters the first duplicate entry (`ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint`).

**What can I do to remove/not save any duplicates while avoiding aborting/failing?** I cannot simply drop the database table and reload it each day. Here is the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160117172450) do

# These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "tablename", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "attr1"
    t.string   "attr2"
    t.string   "attr3"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "tablename", ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"], name: "index_tablename_on_attr1_and_attr2_and_attr3", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

and my rake task in lib/tasks/file_name.rake contents:

```
desc "Download data and update database table"

task :update_task => :environment do
  u = CorrectClassName.new
  u.perform_this
end
```

and `CorrectClassName` is in an .rb file in app/directory1:

```
class CorrectClassName

  def perform_this
    something = ClassWithUpdateCode.new
    something.update_database
  end

end
```

and `ClassWithUpdateCode` is in an .rb file in app/directory2:

```
require 'csv'

class ClassWithUpdateCode

  def update_database
    csv_update = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'assets', "file_name.csv"))
    options = {:headers => true}

    csv = CSV.parse(csv_update, options)
    csv.each do |row|
        tm = TableModel.new

        tm.attr1 = row[0]
        tm.attr2 = row[1]
        tm.attr3 = row[2]
        tm.save # maybe I can use a different method or if statement here?
    end
  end

end
```

**Update: @Kristan's solution works below, but here is where to put the begin/rescue/end handling:**

In the .rb file in app/directory2:

```
require 'csv'

class ClassWithUpdateCode

  def update_database
    csv_update = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'assets', "file_name.csv"))
    options = {:headers => true}

    csv = CSV.parse(csv_update, options)
    csv.each do |row|
        tm = TableModel.new
        begin
          tm.attr1 = row[0]
          tm.attr2 = row[1]
          tm.attr3 = row[2]
          tm.save
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
        end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?  9.5 adds support for. `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`

Comment: This may very well work (I am using 9.5), Tom...I just haven't tried raw SQL before! At some point in the future, I will need to speed up by not using the csv parsing and probably have /copy from and perhaps your SQL suggestion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake` is bailing out because an exception gets raised when you try to save a record that violates your table's uniqueness constraint. The simplest way to prevent that is by catching and ignoring the exception. I'm assuming your record is created during `u.perform_this`.

```rb
task :update_task => :environment do
  u = CorrectClassName.new
  begin
    u.perform_this
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    # move on
  end
end
```

Another option is to add a [uniqueness validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) to your Rails model, then either check `valid?` before saving or call `create` (not `create!`), which doesn't raise validation exceptions.

```rb
class CorrectClassName < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :attr1, scope: [:attr2, :attr3]
end
```

```rb
task :update_task => :environment do
  u = CorrectClassName.new(data)
  u.perform_this if u.valid?
end
```

Comment: I was probably too wordy and also should have included the underlying method within "perform_this". The solution needs to (a) honor the uniqueness validation without (b) raising exceptions and aborting/failing. When I tried the begin/rescue/end solution, (b) was solved but not (a)--the table now has duplicates. Same with "if u.valid?" (even when "if u.valid?" is used in conjunction with the perform_this .save method...which I just updated in the event there's a solution).

Comment: If you have a unique database index on those attributes, it's impossible to end up with duplicates. Are you sure you've configured things properly?

Comment: Ah, interesting...I needed to remove attr3 as a uniqueness constraint--thanks for helping me find that! Still, without the offending attr3 constraint, the begin/rescue/end handling does eliminate exceptions being raised...but the table is not updated (so the rake task is being aborted somehow). Is there some equivalent "move to next" syntax I should use between `rescue` and `end`?

Comment: Also, there still is an error with the `.valid?` solution. My custom class `CorrectClassName` is not recognized when inheriting ActiveRecord::Base...I get a `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "file_name" does not exist` (where "file_name" is the .rb in app/directory1 in my code above, NOT in app/models).

Comment: Ah hah! Okay, when trying to be concise in the question, I made it hard for you to answer. The key is that you said "I'm assuming your record is created during `u.perform_this`." My apologies, the record is actually created _inside_ the `update_database` method (in class `ClassWithUpdateCode` above). So, `begin` `rescue` `end` works when I place it inside the do loop in that method.