# Active Record Query to filter without duplicate records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Could anyone help me to filter the records without duplicates

Here is the PurchaseOrder table with id, job_number, descriptiom and order number fields. If I search a job number 348282227 from this table we can see here line number 2 with id 6678 and 6686 is duplicated with same description and order number. How can I get results without 6686 row.

```
    +-------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+
| id    | job_number | description                  | order_number |
+-------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+
|  6677 | 348282227  | Moisture Inspection 1        | 224201       |
|  6678 | 348282227  | Inspection 3                 | 224202       |
|  6679 | 348282227  | Moisture Inspection Final    | 224203       |
|  6680 | 348282227  | BFP Certification Inspection | 224204       |
|  6681 | 348282227  | Structural Engineering       | 224206       |
|  6682 | 348282227  | Frame Labor 8                | 224218       |
|  6683 | 348282227  | Stucco Turnkey #3            | 224244       |
|  6684 | 348282227  | Retention - Stucco           | 224245       |
|  6685 | 348282227  | Roofing Turnkey              | 224246       |
|  6686 | 348282227  | Inspection 3                 | 224202       |
+-------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+
```

Tried the below query but not works.

```
    uniq_order_numbers = PurchaseOrder.where(job_number: "348282227").pluck(:order_number).uniq
    PurchaseOrder.where(order_number: uniq_order_numbers).select(:job_number, :description, :order_number)
```

Can anyone help me for this.

Comment: group by :job_number, :description, :order_number.

Comment: Not sure what the question. The ids are different which means that it is not a duplicate just that it was put on the same order twice. You can prevent this via validation however your relationships are unclear at the moment

Answer (score 1):

You can go the uniq route, as dbugger suggests:

https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/08/ruby-uniq-method/

But the real issue is that you have duplicate data in your database.  You should probably not be permitting that - either at the record level or/also (ideally) at the database level.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

[How do I make a column unique and index it in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449459/how-do-i-make-a-column-unique-and-index-it-in-a-ruby-on-rails-migration#1449466)